# Can someone tell me what "min" means in this context?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am attempting to write a function (programming, not mathematics) which calculates the shortest distance between two points on a toroid.  I got the following formula from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123947/calculate-distance-between-two-x-y-coordinates), but I don't recognize the `min` portion.  Can someone explain that to me, please?

```
sqrt(min(|x1 - x2|, w - |x1 - x2|)^2 + min(|y1 - y2|, h - |y1-y2|)^2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the question you reference, this toroid is created by identifying the sides of a rectangle $w$ units wide in the x direction and $h$ units high in the y direction.  So assume you have two points $(x_1, y)$ and $(x2, y)$, at the same height and let $x_2>x_1$.  To get from $(x_2, y)$ to $(x_1, y)$ you can either go left by a distance $(x_2-x_1)$, or you can go right (off the edge) and come around a distance of $(w-x_2)+x_1$.  The min just picks smaller of these.  Similarly in y.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I read through the other answers and figured that out, but I appreciate your answer.